# Can a function templates return type depend on the same function templates return type recursively?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang

MSVC and GCC accept the following code but clang rejects it, who is right?

```
template<typename A>
struct S {
    static auto f()->int {
        return 1;
    }
    template<typename T, typename...Ts>
    static auto f(T, Ts...args)->decltype(f(args...)) {
        return{};
    }
};
using d = decltype(S<int>::f(1,2,3,4));
```

Clang error is:

> 1>sortTest2.cpp(113,20): error : no matching function for call to 'f'
>   1>  using d = decltype(S::f(1,2,3,4)); 1>
>   ^~~~~~~~~ 1>  sortTest2.cpp(109,14) :  note: candidate template
>   ignored: substitution failure [with T = int, Ts = ]:
>   too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 3 1>
>   static auto f(T, Ts...args)->decltype(f(args...)) { 1>
>   ^                           ~~~~ 1>  sortTest2.cpp(105,14) :  note:
>   candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 4 were
>   provided 1>          static auto f()->int { 1>                      ^

Comment: Oops sorry, this is an exact duplicate. Looking at the other question though I think I would have been hard pressed to find it.